# Caps-Lock delay issue in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, capslock

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I have recently started duel-booting Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 for the purposes of game development and I have noticed an issue that I think many have had it before me...

When I'm writing I tend to use caps-lock a lot instead of shift to type capital characters, when I turn it on on Ubuntu (and I have tried some other distros like Pop, Fedora, Mint, Manjaro, etc...) it tends to be delayed a little when I try and turn it off and it results in text that looks similar to this: HEllo MY FRiend

I have looked up everywhere and found some scripts that suggested they fix this issue but they didn't work for this version of Ubuntu and most other modern versions of the other Linux distros I tried.

I would like to know if there's any way I can fix this issue? Learning to use shift instead of caps-lock will require lots of time and I can't afford to waste time nowadays.

Notes:

- I have a relatively new mechanical keyboard (bought last month).
- I DO NOT get this issue on macOS or Windows.

Comment: I just use shift now.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely solution, tricky one, but it Worked for me.

Go settings > universal access > **repeat keys** (in typing section)

Reduce down the **delay** section **a little is enough**.

me also get used to use caps lock instead of shift and everybody answers this question as simply learn shift, caps lock is not produced for that. Oh really we didn't know that :)

It also increases the character deleting speed which comes similar to Windows settings.